# Passing object variable in apollo garphql angular gives invalid value

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I am using Angular Front-end to create a client in a graphql server where the input data is an object. This is my code snippet below:

```
const createClient =   gql`
mutation createClient($client: ClientInput!){
  createClient(client: $client){
    lastName
    organization
  }
}
`;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-client',
  templateUrl: './new-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-client.component.scss']
})

export class NewClientComponent implements OnInit {
  subClient = new Client ('', '', '', '');
  submitted = false;
  loading = true;
  data: any;

 public modalRef: BsModalRef;

 constructor(private modalService: BsModalService,
    private router: Router,
    private apollo: Apollo ) {}

 public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
      }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCreateSubmit() {

    const newClient = {
          firstname         : this.subClient.firstName,
          lastname          : this.subClient.lastName,
          organization      : this.subClient.organization,
          email             : this.subClient.email
            };
    this.apollo.mutate({
        mutation: createClient,
        variables: {
           client : newClient
        }
       }).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('new client created: ' + data);
           });
   }
 }
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: GraphQL error: Variable "$client" got invalid value {"firstname":"ewrer","lastname":"ertrt","organization":"rtrt","email":"ytytyy"}.
In field "firstname": Unknown field.
In field "lastname": Unknown field.
In field "firstName": Expected "String!", found null.
In field "lastName": Expected "String!", found null.
Error: GraphQL error: Variable "$client" got invalid value
```

Which seems to related to how I am presenting the variable entry "client". If I replace

```
{
               client : newClient
            }
```

with

```
{
   'client':  {
   'firstName': 'Paul',
   'lastName': 'Smith',
   'organization': 'Truckers Association',
   'email': 'abc123@truckers.com'
   }
 }
```

it works fine. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error messages indicate, the object assigned to your `newClient` variable is missing two required properties -- `firstName` and `lastName`. You've unintentionally misnamed those properties `firstname` and `lastname` (all lowercase).